# What is the correct Fonts and Colours option to change of the Xml value in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, fonts, colors

I have tried most of the related `XML*` colour options from the `Fonts and Colors`  but can not seem to find the correct one that changes the colour of the blue text in the picture below. In addition, none of them have a blue(or related) colour associated with them. This blue text appears for all `name` attributes.

The snippet is from an `app.config` file. What is the correct `Fonts and Colors` option I can use to change the colour of the `name` value?

[image: Blue text that needs to change]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just done some tests and changing the "XML Attribute Value" foreground colour to bold and purple seems to work using this test XML

```
<targets>
  <column name="test" layout="${}"/>  
</targets>
```

In visual studio it looks like this

[image: Visual studio text screen shot]

If you've tried that and it doesn't work then maybe one of your plugins is interfering, in this case try disabling all your extensions and see if that fixes the problem.

---

*Correct solution*

Since this pointed me in the correct direction, it would *seem* that the `VSCommands` extension adds additional options for Fonts and Colors which override the default ones. These remain in Visual Studio even after uninstalling the extension.

[image: Fonts and Colors showing additional XML options]

Comment: I have tried this to no avail. My current `XML Attribute Value` is set to the *green* colour you see above

Comment: Did you disable all your extensions?